# Sequential Type Casting of User Defined Type in C++

Tags: c++, casting

This code compiles and runs with either a public implicit bool cast (commented out below, at http://ideone.com/FDJHB) or through a public implicit int cast followed by an implicit int to bool cast (as shown below, http://ideone.com/kHQ46). However, making the bool cast private (commented out below, at http://ideone.com/4poze) causes a compilation error. Why is the route through int no longer an option in that case? Do sequential casts like this have defined behavior? Thanks.

http://ideone.com/kHQ46

```
#include <iostream>

class MyObject {
 public:
  MyObject(int theInt) : theInt_(theInt) {
    return;
  }

  MyObject& operator=(MyObject& source) {
    std::cout << "assign op" << std::endl;
    theInt_ = source.theInt_;
    return *this;
  }

  friend MyObject operator*(MyObject& lhs, MyObject& rhs);

  operator int() {
    std::cout << "int conv" << std::endl;
    return theInt_;
  }

/*
  operator bool() {
    std::cout << "bool conv" << std::endl;
    return theInt_;
  }
*/

 private:

  int theInt_;

  MyObject(MyObject& source);
//  operator bool();

};

MyObject operator*(MyObject& lhs, MyObject& rhs) {
  std::cout << "mult op" << std::endl;
  return MyObject(lhs.theInt_*rhs.theInt_);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  MyObject a(1);
  MyObject b(2);
  MyObject c(3);

  if (a * b = c) std::cout << "Oh-no!" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: As requested, the relevant compiler messages.

1) Output for the code as given, cast to int to bool:

mult op

int conv

assign op

int conv

Oh-no!

2) Output for the code with public bool cast:

mult op

int conv

assign op

bool conv

Oh-no!

3) Compiler error if bool cast made private:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
prog.cpp:34: error: ‘MyObject::operator bool()’ is private
prog.cpp:50: error: within this context
```

Comment: Are you saying that when you uncomment the public definition of `operator bool` the code still compiles, but when you also uncomment the private declaration, it then fails to compile?

Comment: Also, please edit your question to include the actual compiler error messages that you get.

Comment: Oli: I added some links to clear this up. Case 1 is public bool cast uncommented, nothing else changed. Case 2 is exactly as is. Case 3 is private cast uncommented, nothing else changed.

Comment: chrisaycock: That part I do expect and it doesn't surprise me. But I don't see why the casts can't go to int to bool if the bool cast for the object is private.

Comment: @Praxeolitic I added that comment before I saw your update. Please ignore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to convert your type to `bool`, the compiler selects the "best" conversion path according to a (fairly complicated) set of rules.

If `operator bool()` is defined, then that provides a better conversion than `operator int()` followed by a conversion from `int` to `bool`; a path with fewer conversions is regarded as "better".

Accessibility isn't taken into account in this process, so it will choose `operator bool()` even though it is private. Then compilation will fail, because `operator bool()` is private.

Comment: Is that set of rules part of the standard or up to the compiler?

Comment: @Praxeolitic: They're defined by the standard (in C++11 parts 4 and 12.3, if you want the gory details).

Answer (score 2):

In short, the compiler picks which method to call first, then checks to see if it's allowed to execute it. When it can see the `operator bool` that's the best match for an `if` check, so it picks that one and then discovers that it's private and can't be used.

Also note that `(a * b = c)` assigns `c` to the temporary returned from the multiplication and then evaluates whether that's zero or nonzero. I can't think of a scenario where such a thing would be useful.